# Memory leak in GeneXus

Tags: genexus

There is a **Web Panel** with a `Grid` with paging based on an *SDT* that is loaded with a *Data Provider*.

If the Grid page is changed and an event that goes to the *Server* is executed, the records of the first page are lost.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, seems you are reporting this already fixed bug stated here: http://www2.gxtechnical.com/portal/hgxppredirect.aspx?15,26,0,,,31988 It would be nice if you specify the version of GeneXus you are using and which code generator too.

Comment: This is **not** a memory leak problem...